# Expose complex type property as primitive property in WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

My data model has an entity with a property which is a complex type. The fact that it is a complex type and not just a primitive type is purely internal. 
What I would like to do, it expose the property on a WCF service to look like a regular primitive string property.

I already have my own reflection-based WCF data service, which iterates the model and builds the corresponding ResourceTypes/ResourceProperties. However, if I simply create the ResourceProperty as primitive with type string, like

```
if (property is my complex type property)
{
    r = ResourceType.GetPrimitiveResourceType(typeof(string));
    resourceProperty = new ResourceProperty(propertyName, ResourcePropertyKind.Primitive, r);
}
```

then the serialization fails, which I can understand, since there is no logic doing the conversion between string and my complex type.

How can this be done?